# Cocoa Touch - Loading AVAudioPlayer

Tags: cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, preloading

I have this code to play a sound but the first time you play it it takes a good 5 seconds to load...

How can I speed this up?

```
-(IBAction)playSound{ //play the cricket noise
 NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cricket_Sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
 audioPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath] error:NULL];
 audioPlayer.delegate = self;
 [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
 [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by putting the following section of your code in `viewDidLoad` so that the `audioPlayer` instance is ready to play before it is asked to actually play the audio:

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cricket_Sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
 audioPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath] error:NULL];
 audioPlayer.delegate = self;
 [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
```